# Suggestion for python graphics library to plot aligned protein sequences

Tags: python, visualization

I'm working towards developing some visualization method for multiple protein sequences and subsequences using PYTHON. I want to  show the alignment of many fragment sequences to the original sequences as well as the position of fragments and the amino acids. The amino acids are to be colored by some physico-chemical properties, something similar but not exactly  as this:

[image]

Can somebody suggest some Python libraries suitable for this type of work? The output can be graphics file like png or interactive graphics or html, doesn't matter really for me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at the biotite package, and more specifically to its `biotite.sequence.graphics` module: https://www.biotite-python.org/apidoc/biotite.sequence.graphics.html#module-biotite.sequence.graphics.

Disclaimer: I haven't used these functionalities myself, apart from using one of their colour schemes for DNA.